# How and when should you define a concept for a collection of user-defined types?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I have a collection of user-defined classes A, B, and C. Each of these classes has a private member function specialized_function. To avoid RTTI, I want to define a template non-member function call_specialized_function that calls these specialized functions.

My classes are:

```
class A{
friend class call_specialized_function;
private:
    void specialized_function(){
}
};
class B{
friend class call_specialized_function;
private:
    void specialized_function(){
}
};
class C{
friend class call_specialized_function;
private:
    void specialized_function(){
}
};
```

My template function is:

```
template<typename T>
void call_specialized_function(T t){
    t.specialized_function();
    // more stuff
}
```

I can optionally replace typename with a user-defined concept.

```
template<concept T> // replace concept with a user-defined concept
void call_specialized_function(T t){
    t.specialized_function();
    // more stuff
}
```

This concept should specify that t has a member function void specialized_function().

It seems to me that best practices would require that you almost always define the concept so that you can catch bad template usage earlier in the compilation process and to communicate to programmers what members your template class requires. However, I don't see many people using concepts, and I'm uncertain if defining a concept for a single small template function is worth the effort.

Comment: "To avoid RTTI, I want to" and how do you plan to store and use those classes?

Comment: Issue you would have with concept there is that the method is `private`...

Comment: "It seems to me that best practices would require that" for me it seems that if you use embedded into language mechanism - virtual functions, instead of ag-hoc simulation of it, it would be more efficient, less error prone and more readable.

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure what you mean. I don't know much about RTTI, but I have read that virtual functions are slower and templates are faster. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: *" I don't see many people using concepts"*. concepts are new: C++20

Comment: Depends on what you actually want but many cases can also be solved by either using virtual function or a combination of Std::variant and Std::visit

Comment: space efficient yes, but time efficient?

Comment: @mana: virtual calls are indeed more costly than regular calls, but I doubt it is the bottleneck in most cases.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm writing a program that solves a specific NP-hard problem exactly. The main loop that will be run O(n!) times constructs and uses these classes. I am suspecting that the cost of RTTI is relevant here.

Comment: "I have read that virtual functions are slower and templates are faster" out of context this statement is really wrong. The same way you can say "cars are faster than trucks". But if you need to move 10tons of coal you immediately will realize that it is not true. Yes templated code usually faster for some tasks as it is compile time. But let's say it is 2 microseconds faster and you spend 10 weeks to implement, debug and release it vs 1 week with RTTI. Do you think somebody would care about that 2 microsends in 99.9% of applications?

Comment: I currently have two questions then: "is it good practice to define the concept here?" and "is RTTI *at all* slower than using this template function?"

Comment: "is RTTI at all slower than using this template function?"  it depends. If you try to reimplement the wheel and simulate RTTI most probably your solution would be slower. And when you have template function that needs to call member of 3 classes last thing I would worry is concept to validate it.

Comment: I'm willing to profile both versions of the code for you guys if someone can just tell me if I should define the concept.

Comment: *"I have a collection of user-defined classes A, B, and C"*, so do you manual dispatch (to avoid RTTI)?

Comment: Is concept meaningful, or a "simple" `requires` does the job?

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not sure what you mean by "manual dispatch", but I'm certainly hoping to not use dynamic dispatch. I'm fine with the compiler creating multiple copies of the templated function for each class A, B, and C. 

As for the concept vs ```requires```, I don't know the difference. I wasn't aware I could avoid defining the concept. I have decided to use ```requires requires``` from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints

Comment: I would compare `concepts` and `requires` to function/functor and lambda, the latter are local and don't require name, the former have name and are more likely to be reused.

Comment: By manual dispatching, I meant that some people, to avoid RTTI, add an enum, do a switch case on it to properly cast the base , or select correct union fields. So do several branches to avoid a virtual call which add indirection for the call (with vtable implementation).